# String_agg for multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have the following select

```
$repairs = DB::select(DB::raw('
            select r.id repair_id, w.name, w.surname
                from repairs r
                    join repair_worker rw on r.id = rw.repair_id
                    join workers w on w.id = rw.worker_id
                where r.vehicle_id = ?
                group by w.name, w.surname, r.id
           '),[$vehicle->id]);
```

and I am trying to get `w.name` and `w.surname` into one field, separated by a comma for example. There is a function `string_agg(column, ',')` but I am having no luck to get it working. I always get syntax error.

My try:

```
$repairs = DB::select(DB::raw('
                select r.id repair_id, string_agg(w.name, w.surname, ', ') workers
                    from repairs r
                        join repair_worker rw on r.id = rw.repair_id
                        join workers w on w.id = rw.worker_id
                    where r.vehicle_id = ?
                    group by r.id
          '),[$vehicle->id]);
```

How would you do it?

I am using the newest Postgresql  9+

Comment: to get w.name and w.surname into one field, separated by a comma, use `concat(w.name,',',w.surname)` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun That's MySQL. PostgreSQL uses `||`

Comment: @Barmar `||` will null the whole concatination if any of columns will be null, concat will not. other wise both work with postgres

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html seems concat is a supported function.  Though I think concat_ws (concat with separator) would be better used here.`concat_ws(',',w.name,w.surname)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `||` operator to perform string concatenation, then aggregate this result.

```
$repairs = DB::select(DB::raw("
    select r.id repair_id, string_agg(w.name || ' ' || w.surname, ', ') workers
    from repairs r
        join repair_worker rw on r.id = rw.repair_id
        join workers w on w.id = rw.worker_id
    where r.vehicle_id = ?
    group by r.id
    "),[$vehicle->id]);
```

Comment: Got this error `Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at end of input
LINE 2: ...lect r.id repair_id, string_agg(w.name || ' ' || w.surname, 
^ (SQL: 
select r.id repair_id, string_agg(w.name || ' ' || w.surname, )`

Comment: You have to escape the quotes inside the string.

Comment: With the code you have now, I get this `Syntax error: 7 ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "') workers ...`

Comment: I don't see why. All the quotes appear to match.

Comment: I've changed the PHP string to use double quotes so we don't need to escape the quotes inside it.

Comment: I might be misreading the intent of the question, but it looks like the OP is just looking for a simple Last comma First name concatenation, and doesn't actually need aggregation.

Comment: @Tofystedeth I think there can be multiple workers assigned to a repair, and he wants a comma-separated list of all their names.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see it now.  It's first last, not last first.

Answer (score 2):

try this?

```
$repairs = DB::select(DB::raw("
                select r.id repair_id, string_agg(concat(w.name, ',',w.surname), ', ') workers
                    from repairs r
                        join repair_worker rw on r.id = rw.repair_id
                        join workers w on w.id = rw.worker_id
                    where r.vehicle_id = ?
                    group by r.id
          "),[$vehicle->id]);
```

Comment: Did not work. I got some error similar to the previous ones.

Comment: Oh wait, nope. It works also. My bad,I forgot to change `'` to `"`. Sorry. Thanks for help anyways. I gotta check out that concat function too.

Comment: The main difference between these solutions is if `w.name` or `w.surname` can be `NULL`. If they can't be null, then `concat` and `||` are equivalent.