# STRING_AGG() use expression inside delimiter (results offset by one iteration)

Tags: postgresql

I am running into a very strange behavior using STRING_AGG and using the expression inside the delimiter. The results are offset (ie the next iteration is shown where the delimiter would go).

I have a column which contains neighborhood names and I am trying to join them together into a string to later use in another query since there are a lot of them and I need to do this dynamically. I've dumbed down the query to the bare essentials and I'm still getting the offset result.

example query:

```
    select  string_agg(neighborho, concat(' as "', neighborho, '", ')) from neighborhoods;
```

Expected result:

```
    Cougar  Mountain / Lakemont as "Cougar  Mountain / Lakemont", 
    Northwest Bellevue as "Northwest Bellevue", 
    West Bellevue as "West Bellevue"... so on
```

The result I'm getting:

```
    Cougar  Mountain / Lakemont as "Northwest Bellevue", 
    Northwest Bellevue as "West Bellevue", 
    West Bellevue as "Bridle Trails"... so on
```

I realize the resulting query makes zero sense, I took other elements out to rule out errors there.

I appreciate the input, thank you!

Comment: Good question, and perhaps your confusion may come from using other DB's group concat functions, such as MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`, which in fact would behave the way you are expecting +1.

Comment: Yes, that's where it's coming from. It's very trippy that using the field name in the delimiters offsets by one but using it in the expression side does not. Very interesting behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `STRING_AGG` on a single call to `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT(neighborho, ' as "', neighborho, '", '), ',')
FROM neighborhood;
```

From the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/functions-aggregate.html), `STRING_AGG` takes two parameters, and the second one is the delimiter.  You are currently passing `as "...` for the delimiter, when you actually appear to just want comma.

Comment: The function takes two parameters, STRING_AGG(expression, delimiter)

Comment: Thanks, I actually misread your answer (I'm really tired) but I came up with it at the same time from another example. Thank you!

Comment: Here's the example I found for reference:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687600/string-agg-for-multiple-columns

Comment: Oh. I just saw your edit. Your original answer had only one argument.